# SQL - to evaluate multiple conditions, is OR faster than AND?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, case, teradata, where-clause

Just wonder how conditional statements work behind the scene.

I am checking if multiple fields are all NULL.

```
-- OR: if there is any NOT NULL value
CASE 
    WHEN field_1 IS NOT NULL OR field_2 IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END

-- AND: if all values are null
CASE 
    WHEN field_1 IS NULL AND field_2 IS NULL 
    THEN 1 ELSE 1 
END
```

Just wonder if it will be faster if I use OR rather than AND, because if condition 1 returns True then other conditions will not be evaluated?

Or it will be the same because all conditions are evaluated independently?

Do all SQL engines work in the same way on this matter? I'm using Teradata

Comment: What part of the query is the case in? `where` or the `select` columns? And do you have a typo? Note you can write it easier without the case: `field_1 IS NOT NULL OR field_2 IS NOT NULL` and `not(field_1 IS NULL AND field_2 IS NULL)`.

Comment: Not all SQL engines would work the same way. Regardless, the difference should be extremely small to worry about. It may make a small difference depending on the distribution of null and not null values (and for Teradata, on your primary index).

Comment: @Schwern It is in SELECT clause. Thanks for sharing the simpler way.

Comment: @Billie_H If it's in the select clause, it will have no effect whether it optimizes via De Morgan's Law or not. All the cost is in filtering and sorting rows, not checking columns of already fetched rows.

Comment: In CASE it's probably evaluated as coded, but as Schwern wrote, you will not see a difference in CPU usage. When you change it to a WHERE-condition Explain will reveal if and how it's rephrased by the optimizer.